# Google voice and video chat plug-in for Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, google, gmail, google-talk

I'd like to send and receive phone calls using my google number over Wifi. To do this in a browser on my ubuntu desktop I have to install the Google voice and video chat plug-in but this dose not seem to be available for Ubuntu ARM devices.

Is there anyway to do this yet on Ubuntu Touch?

Comment: Sadly not currently.